# Wordpress Learndash: Custom Settings Metabox field for Topic Display and Content Options

Tags: wordpress, plugins

In the Settings of each Topic and each Lesson of Learndash, we have the option to enable Assignment Uploads as shown in the screenshot. On enabling 'Assignment Uploads' with toggle switch it shows fields like File Extensions, File Size Limit, etc. I need to add an additional field called 'Assignment Description', above or below 'File Extensions'. 'Assignment Description' field will also be shown only when 'Assignment Uploads' is enabled.

There is a file 'includes\settings\settings-metaboxes\class-ld-settings-metabox-topic-display-content.php inside Learndash plugin folder which has code of it as shown below.

```
<?php
/**
 * LearnDash Settings Metabox for Topic Display and Content Options.
 *
 * @package LearnDash
 * @subpackage Settings
 */

if ( ( class_exists( 'LearnDash_Settings_Metabox' ) ) && ( ! class_exists( 'LearnDash_Settings_Metabox_Topic_Display_Content' ) ) ) {
    /**
     * Class to create the settings section.
     */
    class LearnDash_Settings_Metabox_Topic_Display_Content extends LearnDash_Settings_Metabox {
    /**
     * Public constructor for class
     */
    public function __construct() {
        // What screen ID are we showing on.
        $this->settings_screen_id = 'sfwd-topic';

        // Used within the Settings API to uniquely identify this section.
        $this->settings_metabox_key = 'learndash-topic-display-content-settings';

        // Section label/header.
        $this->settings_section_label = esc_html__( 'Display and Content Options', 'learndash' );

        // Used to show the section description above the fields. Can be empty.
        $this->settings_section_description = sprintf(
            // translators: placeholder: topic.
            esc_html_x( 'Controls the look and feel of the %s and optional content settings', 'placeholder: topic', 'learndash' ),
            learndash_get_custom_label_lower( 'topic' )
        );

        add_filter( 'learndash_metabox_save_fields_' . $this->settings_metabox_key, array( $this, 'filter_saved_fields' ), 30, 3 );

        // Map internal settings field ID to legacy field ID.
        $this->settings_fields_map = array(
            // New fields
            'topic_materials_enabled'            => 'topic_materials_enabled',
            'topic_materials'                    => 'topic_materials',

            'lesson_video_enabled'               => 'lesson_video_enabled',
            'lesson_video_url'                   => 'lesson_video_url',
            'lesson_video_shown'                 => 'lesson_video_shown',
            'lesson_video_auto_start'            => 'lesson_video_auto_start',
            'lesson_video_show_controls'         => 'lesson_video_show_controls',
            'lesson_video_auto_complete'         => 'lesson_video_auto_complete',
            'lesson_video_auto_complete_delay'   => 'lesson_video_auto_complete_delay',
            'lesson_video_hide_complete_button'  => 'lesson_video_hide_complete_button',
            'lesson_video_show_complete_button'  => 'lesson_video_show_complete_button',

            'lesson_assignment_upload'           => 'lesson_assignment_upload',
            'assignment_upload_limit_extensions' => 'assignment_upload_limit_extensions',
            'assignment_upload_limit_size'       => 'assignment_upload_limit_size',
            'lesson_assignment_points_enabled'   => 'lesson_assignment_points_enabled',
            'lesson_assignment_points_amount'    => 'lesson_assignment_points_amount',
            'assignment_upload_limit_count'      => 'assignment_upload_limit_count',
            'lesson_assignment_deletion_enabled' => 'lesson_assignment_deletion_enabled',
            'auto_approve_assignment'            => 'auto_approve_assignment',

            'forced_lesson_time_enabled'         => 'forced_lesson_time_enabled',
            'forced_lesson_time'                 => 'forced_lesson_time',
            //'forced_lesson_time_cookie_key'      => 'forced_lesson_time_cookie_key',
        );

        parent::__construct();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the metabox settings values.
     */
     public function load_settings_values() {
       //code to load setting fields values
     }

    /**
     * Initialize the metabox settings fields.
     */
    public function load_settings_fields() {
        global $sfwd_lms;

        $this->setting_option_fields = array(
            'lesson_video_auto_complete'        => array(
                'name'      => 'lesson_video_auto_complete',
                'type'      => 'checkbox-switch',
                'label'     => sprintf(
                    // translators: placeholder: Topic.
                    esc_html_x( '%s auto-completion', 'placeholder: Topic', 'learndash' ),
                    learndash_get_custom_label( 'topic' )
                ),
                'default'   => '',
                'value'     => $this->setting_option_values['lesson_video_auto_complete'],
                'options'   => array(
                    ''   => '',
                    'on' => '',
                ),
                'help_text' => sprintf(
                    // translators: placeholder: topic.
                    esc_html_x( ' Automatically mark the %s as completed once the user has watched the full video.', 'placeholder: topic', 'learndash' ),
                    learndash_get_custom_label_lower( 'topic' )
                ),
            ),
            'lesson_video_auto_complete_delay'  => array(
                'name'        => 'lesson_video_auto_complete_delay',
                'label'       => esc_html__( 'Completion delay', 'learndash' ),
                'type'        => 'number',
                'class'       => '-small',
                'default'     => 0,
                'value'       => $this->setting_option_values['lesson_video_auto_complete_delay'],
                'attrs'       => array(
                    'step' => 1,
                    'min'  => 0,
                ),
                'input_label' => esc_html__( 'seconds', 'learndash' ),
                'help_text'   => sprintf(
                    // translators: placeholder: topic.
                    esc_html_x( 'Specify a delay between video completion and %s completion.', 'placeholder: topic', 'learndash' ),
                    learndash_get_custom_label_lower( 'topic' )
                ),
                'default'     => 0,
            ),
            'lesson_video_show_complete_button' => array(
                'name'      => 'lesson_video_show_complete_button',
                'label'     => esc_html__( 'Mark Complete Button', 'learndash' ),
                'type'      => 'checkbox-switch',
                'help_text' => sprintf(
                    // translators: placeholder: lesson.
                    esc_html_x( 'Display the Mark Complete button on a %s even if not yet clickable.', 'placeholder: lesson', 'learndash' ),
                    learndash_get_custom_label_lower( 'lesson' )
                ),
                'value'     => $this->setting_option_values['lesson_video_show_complete_button'],
                'default'   => '',
                'options'   => array(
                    'on' => '',
                ),
            ),
        );
        parent::load_settings_fields();
        $this->settings_sub_option_fields['video_display_timing_after_fields'] = $this->setting_option_fields;

        $this->setting_option_fields = array(
            'assignment_upload_limit_count'      => array(
                'name'        => 'assignment_upload_limit_count',
                'label'       => esc_html__( 'Limit number of uploaded files', 'learndash' ),
                'type'        => 'number',
                'value'       => $this->setting_option_values['assignment_upload_limit_count'],
                'default'     => '1',
                'class'       => 'small-text',
                'input_label' => esc_html__( 'file(s) maximum', 'learndash' ),
                'attrs'       => array(
                    'step' => 1,
                    'min'  => 1,
                ),
                'help_text'   => esc_html__( 'Specify the maximum number of files a user can upload for this assignment.', 'learndash' ),
            ),
            'lesson_assignment_deletion_enabled' => array(
                'name'      => 'lesson_assignment_deletion_enabled',
                'label'     => esc_html__( 'Allow file deletion', 'learndash' ),
                'type'      => 'checkbox-switch',
                'value'     => $this->setting_option_values['lesson_assignment_deletion_enabled'],
                'default'   => '',
                'help_text' => esc_html__( 'Allow the user to delete their own uploaded files. This is only possible up until the assignment has been approved.', 'learndash' ),
                'options'   => array(
                    'on' => '',
                ),
                'default'   => 0,
            ),
        );
        parent::load_settings_fields();
        $this->settings_sub_option_fields['lesson_assignment_grading_manual_fields'] = $this->setting_option_fields;

        $this->setting_option_fields = array(
            'topic_materials_enabled'            => array(
                'name'                => 'topic_materials_enabled',
                'type'                => 'checkbox-switch',
                'label'               => sprintf(
                    // translators: placeholder: Topic.
                    esc_html_x( '%s Materials', 'placeholder: Topic', 'learndash' ),
                    learndash_get_custom_label( 'topic' )
                ),
                'help_text'           => sprintf(
                    // translators: placeholder: topic, topic.
                    esc_html_x( 'List and display support materials for the %1$s. This is visible to any user having access to the %2$s.', 'placeholder: topic, topic', 'learndash' ),
                    learndash_get_custom_label_lower( 'topic' ),
                    learndash_get_custom_label_lower( 'topic' )
                ),
                'value'               => $this->setting_option_values['topic_materials_enabled'],
                'default'             => '',
                'options'             => array(
                    'on' => sprintf(
                        // translators: placeholder: topic.
                        esc_html_x( 'Any content added below is displayed on the %s page', 'placeholder: topic', 'learndash' ),
                        learndash_get_custom_label_lower( 'topic' )
                    ),
                    ''   => '',
                ),
                'child_section_state' => ( 'on' === $this->setting_option_values['topic_materials_enabled'] ) ? 'open' : 'closed',
            ),
            'topic_materials'                    => array(
                'name'           => 'topic_materials',
                'type'           => 'wpeditor',
                'parent_setting' => 'topic_materials_enabled',
                'value'          => $this->setting_option_values['topic_materials'],
                'default'        => '',
                'placeholder'    => esc_html__( 'Add a list of needed documents or URLs. This field supports HTML.', 'learndash' ),
                'editor_args' => array(
                    'textarea_name' => $this->settings_metabox_key . '[topic_materials]',
                    'textarea_rows' => 3,
                ),

            ),
            'lesson_video_enabled'               => array(
                'name'                => 'lesson_video_enabled',
                'label'               => esc_html__( 'Video Progression', 'learndash' ),
                'type'                => 'checkbox-switch',
                'help_text'           => sprintf(
                    // translators: placeholder: Course.
                    esc_html_x( 'Require users to watch the full video as part of the %s progression. Use shortcode [ld_video] to move within the post content.', 'placeholder: Course', 'learndash' ),
                    learndash_get_custom_label_lower( 'course' )
                ),
                'value'               => $this->setting_option_values['lesson_video_enabled'],
                'default'             => '',
                'options'             => array(
                    ''   => '',
                    'on' => array(
                        'label'       => sprintf(
                            // translators: placeholder: Course.
                            esc_html_x( 'The below video is tied to %s progression', 'placeholder: Course', 'learndash' ),
                            learndash_get_custom_label_lower( 'course' )
                        ),
                        'description' => '',
                        'tooltip'     => sprintf(
                            // translators: placeholder: Topic.
                            esc_html_x( 'Cannot be enabled while %s timer or Assignments are enabled', 'placeholder: Topic', 'learndash' ),
                            learndash_get_custom_label( 'topic' )
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
                'child_section_state' => ( 'on' === $this->setting_option_values['lesson_video_enabled'] ) ? 'open' : 'closed',
            ),
            'lesson_video_url'                   => array(
                'name'           => 'lesson_video_url',
                'label'          => esc_html__( 'Video URL', 'learndash' ),
                'type'           => 'textarea',
                'class'          => 'full-text',
                'value'          => $this->setting_option_values['lesson_video_url'],
                'default'        => '',
                'placeholder'    => esc_html__( 'Input URL, iFrame, or shortcode here.', 'learndash' ),
                'attrs'          => array(
                    'rows' => '1',
                    'cols' => '57',
                ),
                'parent_setting' => 'lesson_video_enabled',
            ),
            'lesson_video_shown'                 => array(
                'name'           => 'lesson_video_shown',
                'label'          => esc_html__( 'Display Timing', 'learndash' ),
                'type'           => 'radio',
                'value'          => $this->setting_option_values['lesson_video_shown'],
                'default'        => 'AFTER',
                'parent_setting' => 'lesson_video_enabled',
                'options'        => array(
                    'BEFORE' => array(
                        'label'       => esc_html__( 'Before completed sub-steps', 'learndash' ),
                        'description' => sprintf(
                            // translators: placeholder: topic.
                            esc_html_x( 'The video will be shown and must be fully watched before the user can access the %s’s associated steps.', 'placeholder: topic', 'learndash' ),
                            learndash_get_custom_label_lower( 'topic' )
                        ),
                    ),
                    'AFTER'  => array(
                        'label'               => esc_html__( 'After completing sub-steps', 'learndash' ),
                        'description'         => sprintf(
                            // translators: placeholder: topic, topic.
                            esc_html_x( 'The video will be visible after the user has completed the %1$s’s associated steps. The full video must be watched in order to complete the %2$s.', 'placeholder: topic, topic', 'learndash' ),
                            learndash_get_custom_label_lower( 'topic' ),
                            learndash_get_custom_label_lower( 'topic' )
                        ),
                        'inline_fields'       => array(
                            'lesson_video_display_timing_after' => $this->settings_sub_option_fields['video_display_timing_after_fields'],
                        ),
                        'inner_section_state' => ( 'AFTER' === $this->setting_option_values['lesson_video_shown'] ) ? 'open' : 'closed',
                    ),
                ),
            ),
            'lesson_video_auto_start'            => array(
                'name'           => 'lesson_video_auto_start',
                'label'          => esc_html__( 'Autostart', 'learndash' ),
                'type'           => 'checkbox-switch',
                'value'          => $this->setting_option_values['lesson_video_auto_start'],
                'default'        => '',
                'options'        => array(
                    'on' => esc_html__( 'The video now starts automatically on page load', 'learndash' ),
                    ''   => '',
                ),
                'parent_setting' => 'lesson_video_enabled',
            ),
            'lesson_video_show_controls'         => array(
                'name'           => 'lesson_video_show_controls',
                'label'          => esc_html__( 'Video Controls Display', 'learndash' ),
                'type'           => 'checkbox-switch',
                'help_text'      => esc_html__( 'Only available for YouTube and local videos.', 'learndash' ),
                'value'          => $this->setting_option_values['lesson_video_show_controls'],
                'default'        => '',
                'options'        => array(
                    ''   => '',
                    'on' => esc_html__( 'Users can pause, move backward and forward within the video', 'learndash' ),
                ),
                'parent_setting' => 'lesson_video_enabled',
            ),

            'lesson_assignment_upload'           => array(
                'name'                => 'lesson_assignment_upload',
                'label'               => esc_html__( 'Assignment Uploads', 'learndash' ),
                'type'                => 'checkbox-switch',
                'default'             => '',
                'value'               => $this->setting_option_values['lesson_assignment_upload'],
                'options'             => array(
                    'on' => array(
                        'label'       => '',
                        'description' => '',
                        'tooltip'     => sprintf(
                            // translators: placeholder: topic.
                            esc_html_x( 'Cannot be enabled while %s timer or Video progression are enabled', 'placeholder: toic', 'learndash' ),
                            learndash_get_custom_label_lower( 'topic' )
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
                'child_section_state' => ( 'on' === $this->setting_option_values['lesson_assignment_upload'] ) ? 'open' : 'closed',
            ),
            'assignment_upload_limit_extensions' => array(
                'name'           => 'assignment_upload_limit_extensions',
                'label'          => esc_html__( 'File Extensions', 'learndash' ),
                'type'           => 'text',
                'placeholder'    => esc_html__( 'pdf, xls, zip', 'learndash' ),
                'help_text'      => esc_html__( 'Specify the type of files users can upload. Leave blank for any.', 'learndash' ),
                'class'          => '-small',
                'default'        => '',
                'value'          => $this->setting_option_values['assignment_upload_limit_extensions'],
                'parent_setting' => 'lesson_assignment_upload',
            ),
            'assignment_upload_limit_size'       => array(
                'name'           => 'assignment_upload_limit_size',
                'label'          => esc_html__( 'File Size Limit', 'learndash' ),
                'type'           => 'text',
                'class'          => '-small',
                'placeholder'    => sprintf(
                    // translators: placeholder: PHP file upload size.
                    esc_html_x( '%s', 'placeholder: PHP file upload size', 'learndash' ),
                    ini_get( 'upload_max_filesize' )
                ),
                'help_text'      => sprintf(
                    // translators: placeholder: PHP file upload size.
                    esc_html_x( 'Default maximum file size supported is: %s', 'placeholder: PHP file upload size', 'learndash' ),
                    ini_get( 'upload_max_filesize' )
                ),
                'default'        => '',
                'value'          => $this->setting_option_values['assignment_upload_limit_size'],
                'parent_setting' => 'lesson_assignment_upload',
            ),

            'lesson_assignment_points_enabled'   => array(
                'name'                => 'lesson_assignment_points_enabled',
                'label'               => esc_html__( 'Points', 'learndash' ),
                'type'                => 'checkbox-switch',
                'default'             => 0,
                'value'               => $this->setting_option_values['lesson_assignment_points_enabled'],
                'options'             => array(
                    'on' => esc_html__( 'Award points for submitting assignments', 'learndash' ),
                    ''   => '',
                ),
                'parent_setting'      => 'lesson_assignment_upload',
                'child_section_state' => ( 'on' === $this->setting_option_values['lesson_assignment_points_enabled'] ) ? 'open' : 'closed',
            ),
            'lesson_assignment_points_amount'    => array(
                'name'           => 'lesson_assignment_points_amount',
                'type'           => 'number',
                'class'          => '-small',
                'attrs'          => array(
                    'step' => 1,
                    'min'  => 0,
                ),
                'default'        => 0,
                'value'          => $this->setting_option_values['lesson_assignment_points_amount'],
                'input_label'    => esc_html__( 'available point(s)', 'learndash' ),
                'parent_setting' => 'lesson_assignment_points_enabled',
            ),

            'auto_approve_assignment'            => array(
                'name'           => 'auto_approve_assignment',
                'label'          => esc_html__( 'Grading Type', 'learndash' ),
                'type'           => 'radio',
                'value'          => $this->setting_option_values['auto_approve_assignment'],
                'parent_setting' => 'lesson_assignment_upload',
                'options'        => array(
                    'on' => array(
                        'label'       => esc_html__( 'Auto-approve', 'learndash' ),
                        'description' => esc_html__( 'No grading or approval needed. The assignment will be automatically approved and full points will be awarded.', 'learndash' ),
                    ),
                    ''   => array(
                        'label'               => esc_html__( 'Manually grade', 'learndash' ),
                        'description'         => sprintf(
                            // translators: placeholder: topic.
                            esc_html_x( 'Admin or group leader approval and grading required. The %s cannot be completed until the assignment is approved.', 'placeholder: topic', 'learndash' ),
                            learndash_get_custom_label_lower( 'topic' )
                        ),
                        'inline_fields'       => array(
                            'lesson_assignment_grading_manual' => $this->settings_sub_option_fields['lesson_assignment_grading_manual_fields'],
                        ),
                        'inner_section_state' => ( '' === $this->setting_option_values['auto_approve_assignment'] ) ? 'open' : 'closed',
                    ),
                ),
            ),

            'forced_lesson_time_enabled'         => array(
                'name'                => 'forced_lesson_time_enabled',
                'label'               => sprintf(
                    // translators: placeholder: Topic.
                    esc_html_x( '%s Timer', 'placeholder: Topic', 'learndash' ),
                    learndash_get_custom_label( 'topic' )
                ),
                'default'             => '',
                'type'                => 'checkbox-switch',
                'value'               => $this->setting_option_values['forced_lesson_time_enabled'],
                'help_text'           => sprintf(
                    // translators: placeholder: topic.
                    esc_html_x( 'The %s cannot be marked as completed until the set time has elapsed.', 'placeholder: topic', 'learndash' ),
                    learndash_get_custom_label_lower( 'topic' )
                ),
                'options'             => array(
                    'on' => array(
                        'label'       => '',
                        'description' => '',
                        'tooltip'     => esc_html__( 'Cannot be enabled while Video progression or Assignments are enabled', 'learndash' ),
                    ),
                ),
                'child_section_state' => ( 'on' === $this->setting_option_values['forced_lesson_time_enabled'] ) ? 'open' : 'closed',
            ),
            'forced_lesson_time'                 => array(
                'name'           => 'forced_lesson_time',
                'type'           => 'timer-entry',
                'class'          => 'small-text',
                'default'        => '',
                'value'          => $this->setting_option_values['forced_lesson_time'],
                'parent_setting' => 'forced_lesson_time_enabled',
            ),
        );

        if ( 'yes' === LearnDash_Settings_Section::get_section_setting( 'LearnDash_Settings_Courses_Builder', 'shared_steps' ) ) {
            unset( $this->setting_option_fields['course'] );
            unset( $this->setting_option_fields['lesson'] );
        }

        $this->setting_option_fields = apply_filters( 'learndash_settings_fields', $this->setting_option_fields, $this->settings_metabox_key );
        // echo "<pre>";
        // print_r($this->setting_option_fields);
        // echo "</pre>";
        parent::load_settings_fields();
    }

    /**
     * Filter settings values for metabox before save to database.
     *
     * @param array $settings_values Array of settings values.
     * @param string $settings_metabox_key Metabox key.
     * @param string $settings_screen_id Screen ID.
     * @return array $settings_values.
     */
    public function filter_saved_fields( $settings_values = array(), $settings_metabox_key = '', $settings_screen_id = '' ) {
        if ( ( $settings_screen_id === $this->settings_screen_id ) && ( $settings_metabox_key === $this->settings_metabox_key ) ) {

            if ( ( 'on' !== $settings_values['topic_materials_enabled'] ) || ( empty( $settings_values['topic_materials'] ) ) ) {
                $settings_values['topic_materials_enabled'] = '';
                $settings_values['topic_materials']         = '';
            }

            // If video progression is enables but the video URL is empty then turn off video progression.
            if ( ( 'on' !== $settings_values['lesson_video_enabled'] ) || ( empty( $settings_values['lesson_video_url'] ) ) ) {
                $settings_values['lesson_video_enabled'] = '';
                $settings_values['lesson_video_url']     = '';
            }

            if ( ( 'on' !== $settings_values['forced_lesson_time_enabled'] ) || ( empty( $settings_values['forced_lesson_time'] ) ) ) {
                $settings_values['forced_lesson_time_enabled'] = '';
                $settings_values['forced_lesson_time']         = '';
                //$settings_values['forced_lesson_time_cookie_key'] = '';
            }

            if ( ( 'on' !== $settings_values['lesson_assignment_points_enabled'] ) || ( empty( $settings_values['lesson_assignment_points_amount'] ) ) ) {
                $settings_values['lesson_assignment_points_amount']  = '';
                $settings_values['lesson_assignment_points_enabled'] = '';
            }

            if ( 'on' === $settings_values['lesson_video_enabled'] ) {
                $settings_values['lesson_assignment_upload']   = '';
                $settings_values['forced_lesson_time_enabled'] = '';
            } elseif ( 'on' === $settings_values['lesson_assignment_upload'] ) {
                $settings_values['lesson_video_enabled']       = '';
                $settings_values['forced_lesson_time_enabled'] = '';
            } elseif ( 'on' === $settings_values['forced_lesson_time_enabled'] ) {
                $settings_values['lesson_video_enabled']     = '';
                $settings_values['lesson_assignment_upload'] = '';
            } else {
                $settings_values['lesson_video_enabled']       = '';
                $settings_values['lesson_assignment_upload']   = '';
                $settings_values['forced_lesson_time_enabled'] = '';
            }

            if ( 'on' !== $settings_values['lesson_video_enabled'] ) {
                $settings_values['lesson_video_url']                  = '';
                $settings_values['lesson_video_shown']                = '';
                $settings_values['lesson_video_auto_start']           = '';
                $settings_values['lesson_video_show_controls']        = '';
                $settings_values['lesson_video_auto_complete']        = '';
                $settings_values['lesson_video_auto_complete_delay']  = '';
                $settings_values['lesson_video_show_complete_button'] = '';
                $settings_values['lesson_video_hide_complete_button'] = '';
            }

            if ( 'on' !== $settings_values['lesson_assignment_upload'] ) {
                $settings_values['assignment_upload_limit_extensions'] = '';
                $settings_values['assignment_upload_limit_size']       = '';
                $settings_values['lesson_assignment_points_enabled']   = '';
                $settings_values['lesson_assignment_points_amount']    = '';
                $settings_values['assignment_upload_limit_count']      = '';
                $settings_values['lesson_assignment_deletion_enabled'] = '';
                $settings_values['auto_approve_assignment']            = '';
            }

            if ( 'on' !== $settings_values['forced_lesson_time_enabled'] ) {
                $settings_values['forced_lesson_time_enabled'] = '';
                $settings_values['forced_lesson_time']         = '';
                //$settings_values['forced_lesson_time_cookie_key'] = '';
            }

            if ( 'on' === $settings_values['lesson_video_enabled'] ) {
                if ( ( 'on' === $settings_values['lesson_video_show_complete_button'] ) ) {
                    $settings_values['lesson_video_hide_complete_button'] = '';
                } else {
                    $settings_values['lesson_video_hide_complete_button'] = 'on';
                }
            }

            if ( 'on' === $settings_values['lesson_assignment_upload'] ) {
                if ( ! empty( $settings_values['assignment_upload_limit_extensions'] ) ) {
                    $settings_values['assignment_upload_limit_extensions'] = learndash_validate_extensions( $settings_values['assignment_upload_limit_extensions'] );
                }

                if ( ! empty( $settings_values['assignment_upload_limit_size'] ) ) {
                    $limit_file_size    = learndash_return_bytes_from_shorthand( $settings_values['assignment_upload_limit_size'] );
                    $wp_limit_file_size = wp_max_upload_size();

                    if ( $limit_file_size > $wp_limit_file_size ) {
                        $settings_values['assignment_upload_limit_size'] = '';
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return $settings_values;
    }

    // End of functions.
}

add_filter(
    'learndash_post_settings_metaboxes_init_' . learndash_get_post_type_slug( 'topic' ),
    function( $metaboxes = array() ) {
        if ( ( ! isset( $metaboxes['LearnDash_Settings_Metabox_Topic_Display_Content'] ) ) && ( class_exists( 'LearnDash_Settings_Metabox_Topic_Display_Content' ) ) ) {
            $metaboxes['LearnDash_Settings_Metabox_Topic_Display_Content'] = LearnDash_Settings_Metabox_Topic_Display_Content::add_metabox_instance();
        }
        /*echo "<pre>";
        print_r($metaboxes);
        echo "</pre>";
        die();*/
        return $metaboxes;
    },
    50,
    1
);
}
```

Since it is Learndash plugin's core file, I don't want to modify it directly rather, via my custom plugin through any hook or overriding I wish to achieve the goal. Please guide.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use the hook as seen in [LearnDash Docs](https://developers.learndash.com/hook/learndash_settings_fields/).
Here is the example from docs, you must adopt it for your metabox key (change the `learndash-course-access-settings`):

```
<?php
/**
 * Example usage for learndash_settings_fields filter.
 */
add_filter(
    'learndash_settings_fields',
    function ( $setting_option_fields = array(), $settings_metabox_key = '' ) {
    // Check the metabox includes/settings/settings-metaboxes/class-ld-settings-metabox-course-access-settings.php line 23 where
    // settings_metabox_key is set. Each metabox or section has a unique settings key.
        if ( 'learndash-course-access-settings' === $settings_metabox_key ) {

        // Add field here.
        $post_id           = get_the_ID();
        $my_settings_value = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'my_meta_key', true );
        if ( empty( $my_settings_value ) ) {
                    $my_settings_value = 'default value';
        }

        if ( ! isset( $setting_option_fields['my-custom-field'] ) ) {
            $setting_option_fields['my-custom'] = array(
                'name'      => 'my-custom-field',
                'label'     => sprintf(
                    // translators: placeholder: Course.
                    esc_html_x( '%s Field Label', 'placeholder: Course', 'learndash' ),
                    learndash_get_custom_label( 'course' )
                ),
                // Check the LD fields ligrary under incldues/settings/settings-fields/
                'type'      => 'text',
                'class'     => '-medium',
                'value'     => $my_settings_value,
                'default'   => '',
                'help_text' => sprintf(
                    // translators: placeholder: course.
                    esc_html_x( 'Some help text for %s.', 'placeholder: course.', 'learndash' ),
                    learndash_get_custom_label_lower( 'course' )
                ),
            );
        }
    }

    // Always return $setting_option_fields
    return $setting_option_fields;
},
30,
2
);

// You have to save your own field. This is no longer handled by LD. This is on purpose.
add_action(
'save_post',
function( $post_id = 0, $post = null, $update = false ) {
    // All the metabox fields are in sections. Here we are grabbing the post data
    // within the settings key array where the added the custom field.
    if ( isset( $_POST['learndash-course-access-settings']['my-custom-field'] ) ) {
        $my_settings_value = esc_attr( $_POST['learndash-course-access-settings']['my-custom-field'] );
        // Then update the post meta
        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'my_meta_key', $my_settings_value );
    }

},
30,
3
);
```

Comment: This example code from learndash doesn't save the custom field. I can get it to show the checkbox-switch, but the $_POST superglobal does not include 'my-custom-field' when the post is updated. Any ideas on why?